# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " in a trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

This is my trigger and i dont know whats wrong with it since it gives me that error

```
create or replace TRIGGER dk_enrolments_insert
AFTER INSERT ON dk_enrolments 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  CURSOR enrolment_cur(e_id dk_enrolments.enrol_id%TYPE) is
  select o.offer_id, a.assmnt_id
  from dk_assessments a, dk_offerings o
  where a.offer_id=o.offer_id 
  AND e_id=:NEW.enrol_id;
 enrolment_rec enrolment_cur%ROWTYPE;
 BEGIN
 OPEN enrolment_cur(:NEW.enrol_id);    
LOOP
    FETCH enrolment_cur INTO enrolment_rec;
    EXIT WHEN enrolment_cur%NOTFOUND;
    insert into dk_deliverables values(deliv_seq.nextval, enrolment_rec.assmnt_id,:NEW.enrol_id);
    END LOOP;
   CLOSE enrolment_cur;
   END;​
```

Comment: Some non-ascii symbol encountered?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is

```
CURSOR enrolment_cur(e_id dk_enrolments.enrol_id%TYPE) is
```

This part: `dk_enrolments.enrol_id%TYPE`

May not resolve to something the parser understands - dk_enrolments.enrol_id

Where is this defined?  If you do not own the object or there is no public synonym for it then you need to include the schema.  I am guessing it is an externally defined column from a table.